# ERROR: type modifier is not allowed for type "date" (PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql

I got an error while creating this function. can you solve it?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_schema.test($1"date") 
   RETURNS date(-1)
   LANGUAGE SQL
   IMMUTABLE
AS $$   
       SELECT (date_trunc('MONTH', $1) + INTERVAL '1 MONTH - 1 day')::date;
$$
;
```

`ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1"`

if I remove the $1 from parameter input the error is:

`type modifier is not allowed for type "date".`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`date(-1)` is invalid. That needs to be just `date`.

The `$1` is also not allowed as a parameter name in the function definition.

You either don't provide a name at all (e.g. `test(date)`- **not** recommended) or you provide a name that is a legal SQL identifier (recommended).

There is also no need to use `$1` when referring to the parameter.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_schema.test(p_input date) 
   RETURNS date
   LANGUAGE SQL
   IMMUTABLE
AS $$   
  SELECT (date_trunc('MONTH', p_input) + INTERVAL '1 MONTH - 1 day')::date;
$$
;
```